# SQLiteDatabase or XML(saving)?

Tags: android, xml, database, sqlite, document

Thanks for making android a wonderful platform.

What is the best option for saving a well formatted document(a document with images) on a device?
I know this can be done by saving to a XML file or on a database, but which of these two is the most preferable.

Thanks in advance.

-Ernest

Answer (score 1):

Usually using XML or SQL database are differents approches for differents needings. Typically a database solution is more efficent than XML.

But XML has a tree structure that is easier to map in a object oriented language. I'll suggest you to use XML for the following reason:

1. easier to load data from xml to an object into your program
2. Easier to modify your page structure (with sql without a ORM system maybe difficult)
3. you are saving a "well formatted document" with images which has a naturally XML representation
4. You are on a mobile device and i don't think you need something like concurrently access to the same XML file or things like that
5. SQL would require installing a database, XML are just a standalone format

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will keep to XML then.

Comment: @Ernest: your welcome. If the answer is enough for you, please flag it as correct. This will close the discussion